# How to create a set from two sets in Hive

Tags: arrays, hive, set, hiveql

I want to create a set from elements in columns coming from two different tables. For the first table `table1`, I want to group elements of the second column according to values at the first column;

```
SELECT Id, collect_set(lib) AS l FROM table1 WHERE (Id LIKE '%RT') GROUP BY ID
```

I get something like this:

```
    |Id|l|
    |1RT|[ab,a1,b5,....]|
    |xRT|[c5,g2,l1,....]|
```

For the second table, I want to select distinct elements from a given column (without any condition) and to merge them with each group calculated from `table1`.

```
     SELECT collect_set(ind) AS d FROM table2
```

I get:

```
   |d|
   |[xy, xz, e1 ,...]|
```

I want to merge the two outputs by combining `d` to each output of `l`. I try the following code:

```
SELECT Id, array(l,d) AS a from(SELECT Id, collect_set(lib) AS l FROM table1 WHERE (Id LIKE '%RT') GROUP BY ID) AS t1 cross join (SELECT collect_set(ind) AS d FROM table2) AS t2
```

But I get two sets in one array:

```
    |Id|a|
    |1RT|[[ab,a1,b5,....],[xy, xz, e1 ,...]]|
    |xRT|[[c5,g2,l1,....],[xy, xz, e1 ,...]]|
```

I want to get one set; something like this:

```
    |Id|a|
    |1RT|[ab,a1,b5,....,xy, xz, e1 ,...]|
    |xRT|[c5,g2,l1,....,xy, xz, e1 ,...]|
```

How can I do? (I used collect_set but it does not work).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use brickhouse `CombineUniqueUDAF` or `CombineUDAF`:

1. Clone ( or fork ) the repo from https://github.com/klout/brickhouse
2. Run "mvn package" from the command line.
3. Add the jar "target/brickhouse-.jar" to your
   HIVE_AUX_JARS_FILE_PATH, or add it to the distributed cache from the
   Hive CLI with the "add jar" command.

Also they have some pre-built jars for [download](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse/wiki/Downloads).

Then create temporary function and use it in the query (along with previous ADD JAR command, provide correct jar name ):

```
ADD JAR /path/to/jar/brickhouse-<version number>.jar;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION combine_unique AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CombineUniqueUDAF';

SELECT Id, combine_unique(l,d) AS a 
 from(SELECT Id, collect_set(lib) AS l FROM table1 WHERE (Id LIKE '%RT') GROUP BY ID) AS t1 
 cross join (SELECT collect_set(ind) AS d FROM table2) AS t2
```